# Program Adds Strings together instead of Integers

Tags: python

I tried to make a calculator using what I learned about Creating my own Functions. I only tried to add two numbers in the beginning. However, when I run the program, It adds the numbers as strings instead of Integers. for example, 12+12 is printed as 1212 instead of 24.

```
def plus(Num1, Num2):
    product = num1 + num2
    print(product)


num1 = input('Enter your number here: ')
int(num1)
num2 = input('Enter another number: ')
int(num2)
op = input('Enter Operator: ')
if op == '+':
    plus(num1, num2)
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the `int` function returns the casted object. So change `int(num1)` to `num1 = int(num1)`. Do this for both inputs

Comment: I got it. That was a dumb mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that just running int(num) doesn't store the value calculated in num. Instead of

```
    int(num)
```

You need

```
    num = int(num)
```

Comment: I understand. Thanks a lot for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

You are not converting properly the `num1` and `num2` values.
Indeed, you have to put the result of your convertions `int(num1)` and `int(num2)` into `num1` and `num2` respectively.
 Your variables are of type `string`, so the `+` operator is applied to strings, so behaves like a **concatenation** operator.
To have a working code, try something like that :

```
def plus(Num1, Num2):
    product = num1 + num2
    print(product)


num1 = input('Enter your number here: ')
num1 = int(num1)
num2 = input('Enter another number: ')
num2 = int(num2)
op = input('Enter Operator: ')
if op == '+':
    plus(num1, num2)
```

Comment: Yeah, I got it. I forgot to update the variables. Thanks for pointing out the mistake!